# How do I loop through a list for a soap API?

Tags: python, xml, soap

I'm new to coding and working on this new cocktail app for a client and could use some assistance. I have to make a soap API call to the client to get data back, but I can only make the call one at a time. What is the best way to make the call serially? I did some searching to find the best way to build the xml file and the file, but I broke something in my code.

```
coctails csv:

cocktail_name,cocktail_base,ingredients,portions in oz,garnish
last word,gin,chartreuse&maraschino&lime,2&3/4th&3/4th&3/4th,cherry
whiskey sour,whiskey,lemon juice&simple syrp,2&3/4&1/2,bitters
```

Here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET



#API Params:

target_url = "https://www.cocktailingredsdemo.com/"

api_headers = {301972e3e060102biwkrw5681rf68afd648ce098af0}

#storing the results:
 api_results = []
error_response = []
with open("cocktail_list.csv") as f: 
   reader = csv.DictReader(f)

   #writing out xml for cocktail list

for i, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
       root = ET.Element('cocktail')
       ET.SubElement(root, "cocktail_name").text = row['cocktail_name']

       ingredientsNode = ET.SubElement(root, "cocktail_ingredients") 
       for code in row['ingredients'].split('&'):
           ET.SubElement(ingredientsNode, "ci").text = code

       ET.SubElement(root, "portions").text = row['portions in oz']
       ET.SubElement(root, "garnish").text = row['garnish']

       cocktail_xml = ET.tostring(root, method='xml', encoding="UTF-8")
       with open(f'cocktail_data.xml', 'wb') as f: 
              f.write(cocktail_xml) 


       response = requests.post(target_url, data=cocktail_xml, headers=api_headers)
       url_response = json.loads(response.text)
       if type(data)==dict and 'error' in data.keys():
           error_response.append(data)
       else:
          results.append(data)
```

This way doesn't work: What happens is the as I loop through each row, I'm only getting the last row back and that last xml is being used to make the API call.

What is the best way to do this so that it loops through each row and makes the api call?

Comment: Try indenting your `for` loop to same level as `reader`. You also do not need to save .xml file since you do not use it for post request and overwrite it with each loop. Also, why `enumerate` if you do not use `i`?

Comment: @Parfait I tried doing that first and it still failed. Would I still call `cocktail_xml` in my request?

Comment: What does *still failed* mean? Still only last row? See [online demo](https://rextester.com/QGOB13340) of your posted data and code (without the post request). As seen from output, with proper indentation each XML corresponds to each row of CSV. And your variable `cocktail_xml` is not the .xml file.

Comment: @Parfait sorry, it's still returning the just the last row from my csv

Comment: Per demo I just set up, I cannot reproduce your issue. Do you agree the demo does not only return last row of CSV?

Comment: @Parfait yeah I can agree with that.

Comment: Then once again check indentation carefully in your actual code. Indents are very important in Python. Your issue of one last row would occur if post request code at bottom is not indented to same level as XML parsing code.

Comment: Do this: [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65513409/edit) your post by copy/paste code exactly. But at the beginning and end of code block place three backticks (which you did not do above). Do NOT indent with StackOverflow editor, `{}`. This will help us see your original spacing.

Comment: @Parfait I made an edit to my code and followed y our instructions.

Comment: Please re-run code and test issue reproduces undesired result since this edit should fail in Python compiler.